# How to stop generating dynamic web api?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have downloaded template and creating sample task application.

From below reference I found Web API auto generated from my task service class.

[Dynamic web api generation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dynamic-Web-API)

So how can I stop this behaviour or make changes in this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out the lines mentioned on that page.

## ASP.NET MVC 5

```cs
// Configuration.Modules.AbpWebApi().DynamicApiControllerBuilder
//     .ForAll<IApplicationService>(typeof(AbpProjectNameApplicationModule).Assembly, "app")
//     .Build();
```

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-template/blob/c0d7f0433d573a8207b27f817e1d188c215f1e50/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.WebApi/Api/AbpProjectNameWebApiModule.cs#L17-L19

## ASP.NET Core

```cs
// Configuration.Modules.AbpAspNetCore()
//     .CreateControllersForAppServices(
//         typeof(AbpProjectNameApplicationModule).GetAssembly()
//     );
```

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/bb9d5aab6e5047d6d22d49831b473c0b3329b499/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Core/AbpProjectNameWebCoreModule.cs#L44-L47

Answer (score 2):

You can easily disable an application service to expose its methods as Web API actions.
Just use `[RemoteService(false)]` attribute on application service class or application service interface.

```cs
[RemoteService(IsEnabled = false)]
public class UserAppService : ApplicationService, IUserAppService
{
   
}
```

*for mass operation, use @aaron's method.*

Comment: Hello ,
What about Abp Modules?  How can I disable AccountAppService ( Abp Module ) to be webapi ?